# When confirming payment intent with Stripe the funds are being hold but the API returns as failed

Tags: android, android-intent, stripe-payments, payment

I am trying to hold funds on the customer card until the trip has been completed.

On the server:

```
> const capture = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
>             customer: stripeId,
>             amount: amount,
>             currency: "gbp",
>             payment_method: paymentId,
>             receipt_email: email,
>             confirm: true,
>             capture_method: "manual",
>             setup_future_usage: "off_session",
>             use_stripe_sdk: true,
>         });
```

Payment intent comes back with status "requires_action" so i try to confirm the hold of funds in the app:

```
>  final PaymentConfiguration paymentConfiguration =
> PaymentConfiguration.getInstance(requireContext());
>             PaymentLauncher paymentLauncher = PaymentLauncher.Companion.create(this,
> paymentConfiguration.getPublishableKey(),
> paymentConfiguration.getStripeAccountId(), this);
> 
> final ConfirmPaymentIntentParams confirmParams = ConfirmPaymentIntentParams.createWithPaymentMethodId(paymentMethodId,
> clientSecret);
>             paymentLauncher.confirm(confirmParams);
```

Funds are being confirmed and the payment intent updates status to "requires_capture", but the payment result callback returns as failed. This card does not really need 3DS but it does return "requires_action" so i need to confirm it. On another card that does require 3DS this method works.

```
@Override
>     public void onPaymentResult(@NonNull PaymentResult paymentResult) {
>         if (paymentResult instanceof PaymentResult.Completed) {
>         } else if (paymentResult instanceof PaymentResult.Canceled) {
>         } else if (paymentResult instanceof PaymentResult.Failed) {
>             Throwable error = ((PaymentResult.Failed) paymentResult).getThrowable();error.getMessage());
>         }
>     }
```

Comment: Seems strange that the PaymentIntent object would move to the next step, but the frontend gets an error. Probably worth writing to Stripe's support team with the full details(the exact PaymentIntent used and details on the card used) to look into it

Comment: I tried 3 times and they come back with same standard message not even understanding what the problem is and how to guide me. They keep saying let's move this chat to email.

Comment: I'd expect to need to email to explain a complex technical question with coding and potential bug to be honest, rather than chat with an initial support agent, so that's probably the way to go.

Comment: I have sent them all the details and why it is a bug but i got back same standard response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using stripe API:

Check status of the returned payment intent and if it requires_action or requires_confirmation use this:

```
Stripe stripe = new Stripe(this, publishable key);
ConfirmPaymentIntentParams confirmPaymentIntentParams = ConfirmPaymentIntentParams.create(response.getString("secret"));
stripe.confirmPayment(this, confirmPaymentIntentParams);
    
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                stripe.onPaymentResult(requestCode, data, new ApiResultCallback<PaymentIntentResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(@NonNull PaymentIntentResult paymentIntentResult) {
                        StripeIntent.Status status = paymentIntentResult.getIntent().getStatus();
                        if (status != null) {
                            switch (status) {
                                case Succeeded:
                                case RequiresCapture:
                                    //all good
                                    break;
                                case RequiresAction:
                                case RequiresConfirmation:
                                    //error i guess
                                    break;
                                case RequiresPaymentMethod:
                                    //no funds
                                    break;
                                case Canceled:
                                    checkPayment();
                                    break;
                            }
                        } else {
                            checkPayment();
                        }
                    }
        
                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        //show error
                    }
                });
            }
```